# .htaccess para impedir navegação

Tags: linux, htaccess, apache

Tenho um servidor Debian e o diretório para por os projetos no apache é o tradicional /var/www/html, estou tentando bloquear a navegação nos diretórios e sub-diretórios pelo browser com o .htaccess mas não estou acertando.

O código do .htaccess esta na pasta html com permissão 644 usuário www-data:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente isto:

```
<Location /my_folder/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Ou isto (depende da versão do server)

```
<directory /my_folder/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

### Configuração do apache

Edit o arquivo de configuração do apache, geralmente em `/etc/apache2.conf` procure a list de diretórios disponíveis, um bloco parecido com esse (copiada de uma maquina virtural debian google cloud):

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**Altere a diretiva `AllowOverride` para:**

```
 AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Tentei as duas formas mas não deu, sera que tem que reiniciar o apache ?

Comment: Embora possa não ser somente isso, mas sim, tem que reiniciar o apahe. `$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Comment: Tentei os dois exemplo e sempre reiniciando o apache e não deu, continua listando... quero que o apache pare de listar as pastas pois ontem eu vi nos logs do apache que alguem ficou chutando alguns diretórios no meu servidor. Se precisar a versão do apache é essa: Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)

Comment: Como assim alguem ficou chutando diretorios? de que forma?

Comment: Criei uma conta free no google cloud, dai criei uma vm com LAMP pra fazer uns testes, essa VM possui um IP variavel para acesso pela internet e que só eu fico sabendo, dai dando uma olhada nos logs do apache para ver outra coisa eu vi que tinham logs de erro pois tentaram acessar de varios SOs diferentes endereços como /html/login, /password, /PASSWOR, /robot.txt ... e por ai vai, por isso quero tirar pelo menos a navegação de arquivos/pastas do Apache! (acho que os piá racudo ficam chutando endereço rsrs)

Comment: Editei a resposta, tente aplicar a configuração indicada no apache.

Comment: Boa! Deu certo! Muito obrigado!