# Bloquear acesso a subpastas na URL (WordPress) a partir do 403 forbidden

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, http-status-404, http-status-code-403

Espero que fique claro  minha dúvida:

Já vi que imagens upadas pela Amazon CloudFront que tem sua URL "diferenciada" para imagens e bloqueia todas as subpastas do caminho se o usuário tentar acessar. Explico.

URL exibindo a imagem: **dyqnik0vds4aw.cloudfront.net/uploads/blog/imagem/900/imagem.jpg**

Se retirarmos o **imagem.jpg**, por exemplo, exibe a seguinte mensagem:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>0A1B7A4F06A544B7</RequestId>
<HostId>
HAvQCyWqXGr6xFPOA4IIZPWudC+TSxyBnjQyMitrHu5cQ9eBk6zbFrHWY82xvMVREzYbnWCtU5g=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

Ou seja, se o usuário tentar acessar qualquer outra subpasta do caminho da imagem é bloqueado.

Contudo estou utilizando o WordPress para criar um site, quando se upa uma imagem, por padrão, ela fica com a URL `site.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/imagem.png`. Se o usuário retirar `/2018/02/imagem.png` (no caso, acessando *site.com/wp-content/uploads/*) a página INDEX OF aparece e é possível acessar algumas pastas, **o que gostaria de evitar se possível.**

Enfim, gostaria de saber se consigo bloquear/esconder o caminho da imagem do jeito como a Amazon CloudFront bloqueia seus links.

```
             ----------------------- *edited* -------------------------------
```

Depois de um tempo mexendo com sites e vendo várias coisas aqui do SOPT, no resumo da opera, o que eu quero é criar uma página `403 forbidden` que além de bloquear as pastas mais especificamente do WordPress seja uma página personalizada.

Acredito que seria apenas incrementar a resposta do @Almeida abaixo.

Comment: Possível duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/214786/htaccess-para-impedir-navega%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Answer (score 1):

bom no meu caso, eu fiz isso no meu site, mas não uso wordpress, mas aconselho você criar um arquivo chamado .htaccess na pasta raiz de seu servidor e criar páginas de erro personalizadas como 404, 403 (acesso proibido) entre outras, feito estes processos, você vai abrir o seu arquivo htaccess e vai inserir isso:

```
###### Regras básicas de reescrita, parar desnecessários bot PERL, bloquear diretórios de subversão

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
ErrorDocument 403 "Acesso proibido"



###### PROTEGER ARQUIVOS E DIRETÓRIOS
<FilesMatch "(\.(engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.html)? |xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template)$">
Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>


###### BLOQUEIO LISTAGEM DE DIRETÓRIOS

<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
    Options -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Comment: no caso só adiciono as pastas do meu diretório na após o `...theme|tpl(\.html)|wp-content|images?` etc. certo?

Answer (score 1):

@vulgogandini

sim, isso depende das necessidades, eu atualmente de modo particular estou usando em todas as pastas de subversão, ou seja as index of, para isso basta um comando simples no seu arquivo .htaccess

## Regras básicas de reescrita, parar desnecessários bot PERL, bloquear diretórios de subversão

**COMANDO:**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?\.svn/ - [F,L]
ErrorDocument 403 "Acesso proibido"`
```

lembrando, que o seu servidor deve esta habilitado o IfModule mod_rewrite.c
para que funcione

resultado após colocar o código no aquivo, é esse: 403 forbiden
isso se dar porque você está negando acesso a todos a todas as pastas index of

veja um site que montei especialmente para esta ocasião como modelo:
http://www.site-space.16mb.com

neste caso se eu tentar acessar o diretório "assets" index of que é a minha pasta dentro do meu servidor, ele me retorna o acesso negado. veja:

http://www.site-space.16mb.com/assets